# Laptop doesn't wake up after suspension

Tags: linux, suspend, laptop

Whenever I enter suspension mode in my laptop, I cannot leave it: I can hear that a fan of the laptop is working, the power indicator shows that the laptop is on, and I can't return to Linux after suspending the session. I must hard-reboot the laptop in order to boot back to Linux.

Distros I've seen this happening in:

- [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_(Bionic_Beaver)) x64
- [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_(operating_system))
- [Mint 19 (Tara)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) x64

Distros in which it doesn't happen:

- [Debian 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) (Stretch)
- [ElementaryOS 0.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#0.4_Loki) (Loki)

Laptop model: Asus X553M.

Does anyone know what is going on, or how to fix this?

Comment: _kometh0616_ there are multiple configurations of the Asus X553M laptop as shown at https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/X553MA/specifications/ and it's important to know which you have. Please look on the underside for the serial number plate, and get the engineering model number, which will be longer. Then, click on [edit] and put that model number in the original question to improve it.

Comment: _kometh0616_, another question: Which kernels are in use? Kernels can be updated frequently. You mentioned Debian 9 (Stretch), but since 9.6 is the current version, it's not clear which kernel is in use for it. Likewise for Ubuntu 18.04, as its current version is 18.04.1. Please open a terminal window, and run _uname -a_ then click on [edit] and expand on your question to show which kernel is in use, and also please show if x86 or x64., as well as the version of Fedora in use. For Mint 19 (Tara), please advise which desktop environment is in use; Cinnamon, Mate, or Xfce.